# Where are filter keys, mouse keys and toggle keys EXE files located?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, filterkeys

I am looking for the locations of EXE files of processes that can be run from the lock screen.

So far I know of sticky keys which is activated by relatedly tapping shift and is located in `C:\Windows\System32\sethc.exe`.

I know there are other features such as filter keys, mouse keys and toggle keys which can be activated by similar shortcuts.

I would like to know the path of the EXEs that run when these are activated, and if there are any other similar shortcuts that can be run on the lock screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This path is different depending on which version of Windows you are using. Windows 7 uses sethc.exe where Windows 8 and 10 use utilmon.exe.

This single program is entirely responsible for the accessibility options (which contains sticky keys, mouse keys, etc) and as far as I know is the only exe that you can start from the logon screen. Things like access to VPN and WIFI are not exefiles as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Although I believe Win+P opens some projector settings even from the logon screen

Comment: Yes, and you can make VPN and WiFi too. But they are all controlled through windows dll's, as far as I know.